# WPF DataGrid bind cell background color to property of assigned Data object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid where the cells are assigned to a custom class defined below:

```
public class DataGridVariableWrapper : DependencyObject
{
    public Variable TheVariable { get; set; }

    public Brush BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue( BackgroundColorProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( BackgroundColorProperty, value ); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "BackgroundColor", typeof( Brush ), typeof( DataGridVariableWrapper ), new UIPropertyMetadata( null ) );

    public DataGridVariableWrapper( Brush backgroundBrush, Variable theVariable )
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = backgroundBrush;
        this.TheVariable = theVariable;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TheVariable.Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to have the DataGridCell background bound to the BackgroundColor property of this data wrapper class.  I've tried:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataGridVariableWrapper.BackgroundColor}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

But the background color remains unchanged.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}"`?

Comment: That seems to have worked, just have to figure out the little white space padding that's showing up rather than a full background fill.

Comment: Got it, had to set the border thickness of the cell to 0.  If you want to make your comment an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a data object is assigned to a `DataGridCell` you will find it in the `DataContext`. That's why all you have to do in binding is to specify the desired property.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}" />
</Style>
```